# How to preserve the table schema when you write dataset out as XML

Tags: c#, sql, xml-serialization, dataset

The heading pretty much explains what I would like to achieve, but here is an example to elaborate further:

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [CustSchema].[TestTable](
    [Desc] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I load this table into a DataTable, and then spit it out again using DataSet.WriteXml(), I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <TestTable>
    <Desc>XROW1</Desc>
  </TestTable>
  <TestTable>
    <Desc>XROW2</Desc>
  </TestTable>
</NewDataSet>
```

Whereas, I would like to preserve the table's schema - ie, get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <CustSchema.TestTable>
    <Desc>XROW1</Desc>
  </CustSchema.TestTable>
  <CustSchema.TestTable>
    <Desc>XROW2</Desc>
  </CustSchema.TestTable>
</NewDataSet>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you add some info on what you'll be doing with this data?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Data.DataSet ds;
ds.WriteXml(*some stream*, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

[System.Data.DataSet.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml(VS.80).aspx)
[XmlWriteMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.xmlwritemode(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately that writes the XML schema, not the table schema - ie:

<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema ...>
 ...
  </xs:schema>
  <Tbl1>
    <Desc>XROW1</Desc>
  </Tbl1>
  <Tbl1>
    <Desc>XROW2</Desc>
  </Tbl1>
</NewDataSet>